# Errors when trying to install nodejs using curl

Tags: node.js

I am working with Angular2 and ionic2 for a while now and everything was fine. a few days ago I upgraded the ionic command line tool and from that point I am not able to create new projects. Here is the scenario:

1. create a new project : "ionic start test2"
2. getting an error: `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/steve/.ionic/helper.log'`
3. continue the process and it is stuck on : "Downloading integration cordova"

I then tried reinstalling nodejs using the command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

and got a bunch of errors:

```
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable Release
Error executing command, exiting
```

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`W: Duplicate sources.list entry error:`

This may be because you has a duplicate source of apt-get,  check this the lists.

***There are two ways for fix this***:

**FIRST WAY:**

1. Comment the source in `sources.list`:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and comment the line

`deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main`

**SECOND WAY:**

1. **Check if vscode or your package is duplicated in the lists:**

   `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`  and the output:

   `google-chrome.list  google-chrome.list.save  nodesource.list  vscode.list`
2. **Comment the line `deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main`:**

My problem is with vscode then check the `vin vscode.list` or the list that has the problem and comment the line

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```